# Send an recieve data do not properly work

Tags: python-3.x, string, sockets, split

I am sending a packt string decoded in bytes from one socket to another. The data is put into a FIFO Queue before send. The server should split the packet into its original configuration when recieved. part1-3 have 3 values each and part 4 has 4 values.

```
#client
sendStr = part1 + "|" + part2 + "|" + part3 + "|" + part4 + " "

sendList.put(sendStr)

self.socket.send(bytes(sendList.get(), "utf-8"))

#server
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

    print(data)

    part1, part2, part3, part4 = data.split('|', 3)

    print(part1)

    print(part2)

    print(part3)

    print(part4)

#Output
-0.16957710683345795~-0.8000791668891907~0.042239610105752945|0.010270391590893269~-0.10846169292926788~0.01289278082549572|-0.0012780826073139906~-0.01820523850619793~0.026601631194353104|0.011026948690414429~0.010662704706192017~0.006311187520623207~0.00 #part is missing
-0.16957710683345795~-0.8000791668891907~0.042239610105752945
0.010270391590893269~-0.10846169292926788~0.01289278082549572
-0.0012780826073139906~-0.01820523850619793~0.026601631194353104
0.011026948690414429~0.010662704706192017~0.006311187520623207~0.00
5033979192376137 #wrong output
#gameLog
-0.16957710683345795~-0.8000791668891907~0.042239610105752945|0.010270391590893269~-0.10846169292926788~0.01289278082549572|-0.0012780826073139906~-0.01820523850619793~0.026601631194353104|0.011026948690414429~0.010662704706192017~0.006311187520623207~0.005033979192376137 #this data gets send
```

I expect the recieved data to look as the send data.

Comment: Try putting `recv` in a loop until all bytes read.

Comment: already had a while loop. I forgot to add it to the post

Comment: What I meant was that it is possible a single call to `recv` is not enough to get the entire message. You need to build the string up by repeatedly calling `recv` until you've got the whole thing. [Python Socket Receive Large Amount of Data](//stackoverflow.com/q/17667903)

Comment: @Hugo54x - You're ending a string with " ". Could you consider ending with "\n"? This would make a simpler implementation possible.